# Calling multiprocessing pool within a function is very slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spacy, pathos

I am trying to use pathos for triggering multiprocessing within a function. I notice, however, an odd behaviour and don't know why:

```py
import spacy
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool as Pool


nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

def preworker(text, nlp):
    return [w.lemma_ for w in nlp(text)]

worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)

texts = ["Este es un texto muy interesante en español"] * 10

# Run this in jupyter:
%%time

pool = Pool(3)
r = pool.map(worker, texts)
```

The output is

```
CPU times: user 6.6 ms, sys: 26.5 ms, total: 33.1 ms
Wall time: 141 ms
```

So far so good... Now I define the same exact calculation, but from a function:

```py
def out_worker(texts, nlp):
    worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)
    pool = Pool(3)
    return pool.map(worker, texts)

# Run this in jupyter:
%%time 

r = out_worker(texts, nlp)
```

The output now is

```
CPU times: user 10.2 s, sys: 591 ms, total: 10.8 s
Wall time: 13.4 s
```

**Why is there such a large difference?** My hypothesis, though I don't know why, is that in the second case a copy of the nlp object is sent to every single job.

Also, **how can I correctly call this multiprocessing from within a function?**

Thanks

---

EDIT:

For reproducibility of the issue, here is a Python script that shows the situation:

```
import spacy
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool as Pool
import time

# Install with python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

def preworker(text, nlp):
    return [w.lemma_ for w in nlp(text)]

worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)

texts = ["Este es un texto muy interesante en español"] * 10

st = time.time()
pool = Pool(3)
r = pool.map(worker, texts)
print(f"Usual pool took {time.time()-st:.3f} seconds")

def out_worker(texts, nlp):
    worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)
    pool = Pool(3)
    return pool.map(worker, texts)

st = time.time()
r = out_worker(texts, nlp)
print(f"Pool within a function took {time.time()-st:.3f} seconds")

def out_worker2(texts, nlp, pool):     
    worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)     
    return pool.map(worker, texts)

st = time.time()
pool = Pool(3) 
r = out_worker2(texts, nlp, pool)
print(f"Pool passed to a function took {time.time()-st:.3f} seconds")
```

In my case, the output is this one:

```
Usual pool took 0.219 seconds
Pool within a function took 8.164 seconds
Pool passed to a function took 8.265 seconds
```

The spacy nlp object is quite heavy (a few MBs). My spacy version is 3.0.3

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  What if you were to build the pool outside of the function, then pass the pool (or map) into the function (as an argument)?  That's generally what I do.

Comment: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/67c714b4052ebd5b91a21ef55bb1d18fad8727ab/examples/async_map.py#L37 or https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/10f241a66db65afca9bc70304f204431cbc2eb57/examples3/ouq_models.py#L56.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I just did it:
```python
def out_worker2(texts, nlp, pool):
    worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)
    return pool.map(worker, texts)

%%time 

pool = Pool(3)
r = out_worker2(texts, nlp, pool)
```

The time was 10.4s

Comment: It could definitely be an issue of what gets serialized in each case.  Can you try your example outside of `Jupyter` (i.e. in a standard python interpreter or just a file)?  Jupyter does some tinkering with globals due to the use of cells in a notebook.  It also would be good to have a self-contained example of the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I just edited my question with a python script. I think the script is pretty much self-contained (even though it uses spacy), which is a heavy NLP model object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of
`from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool as Pool`, I used
`from multiprocess import Pool`, which is essentially the same thing.  Then I tried some alternative approaches.

So:

```
from multiprocess import Pool
```

yields `0.1s` for the "usual" case and `12.5s` for the other two cases.

However:

```
from multiprocess import Pool
import dill 
dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```

yields `12.5s` for all three cases.

Lastly:

```
from multiprocess.dummy import Pool
```

yields `0.1s` for all three cases.

What this tells me is that it's definitely a serialization issue, and that it's the serialization of `globals` that is the key to the speed.

In the first case, the default `dill` behavior is to try to avoid recursing through `globals` if possible.  It is able to do this successfully for the "usual" way, but not for the other two calls inside a function.

When I first import `dill` and switch the behavior of globals to `recurse` (this is how `cloudpickle` does it's pickling), then it's slow in all three tries (the "usual" way included).

Lastly, if I use `multiprocess.dummy`, and thus a `ThreadPool` -- it doesn't need to serialize globals, and you can see it's fast in all cases.

Conclusion: use `pathos.pools.ThreadPool` or `multiprocess.dummy.Pool` if that's feasible. Otherwise, make sure that you are running in such a way that you aren't serializing globals.

There is a helpful tool in `dill` that you can use to see what's getting serialized.  If you include `dill.detect.trace(True)`, then dill spits out a bunch of codes for the objects it is serializing as it recursively pickles the object and it's dependencies.  You have to look at the `dill` source code to match the key (e.g. `F1` is a particular type of function object, and `D1` is a particular type of dictionary). You can see how the different approaches serialize different underlying objects.  I unfortunately don't have a profiler on it, so you can't see immediately where the speed hit is, but you can see the different strategies it takes.

I'd just try avoid serializing the `nlp` object, or whatever it is that is causing the slowdown (probably the `nlp` object).

So for example, instead of passing the nlp object in the function, you can do this instead:

```
import spacy
from multiprocess import Pool
import time

# Install with python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

def preworker(text, nlp):
    return [w.lemma_ for w in nlp(text)]

worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)

texts = ["Este es un texto muy interesante en espanol"] * 10

st = time.time()
pool = Pool(3)
r = pool.map(worker, texts)
pool.close(); pool.join()
print("Usual pool took {0:.3f} seconds".format(time.time()-st))

def out_worker(texts):
    worker = lambda text: preworker(text, nlp)
    pool = Pool(3)
    res = pool.map(worker, texts)
    pool.close(); pool.join()
    return res

st = time.time()
r = out_worker(texts)
print("Pool within a function took {0:.3f} seconds".format(time.time()-st))
```

By passing `nlp` by reference lookup instead of explicitly through the function arguments, the speed was `0.1s` for both cases.